# MySQL query is slower after index create

Tags: mysql, indexing

At first i will write some information about my test table.
This is books table with 665647 rows of data.
Below you can see how it looks.

[image]

I made 10 same queries for books with price equal

```
select * from books where price = 10
```

Execution time for all 10 queries was 9s 663ms.

After that i created index which you can see here:
[image]

i tried to run same 10 queries one more time.
Execution time for them was 21s 996ms.

```
show index from books;
```

Showed very wired data for me.
Possible value is just one!

[image]

SHOW CREATE TABLE books

Result:

```
    CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `isbn` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` double(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `books_isbn_unique` (`isbn`),
  KEY `books_author_id_foreign` (`author_id`),
  KEY `books_price_index` (`price`),
  CONSTRAINT `books_author_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=665648 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

What did i wrong? I was sure indexes are thing that can make our queries faster, not slower.